# never ending Powershell script when executed from SQL Server Agent

Tags: powershell

My PowerShell script is unable to create a PS-Session when executed through SQL Server Agent Job,
On the other hand when I tried to execute the script from powershell editor it is running fine.

I tried to catch output into a text file which shows script is executing fine until-------

> `echo "Credentials received"  >> C:\Users\username\Desktop\ABC.txt`

```
#Set Execution policy for the first run
#Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

#This is better for scheduled jobs
$User = "xyz@abc.com"
$pass = "0100skdhfsdhlfsj7eb0100000044afdcf1458d41449af94347f8d9d962000012464664603660000c000000010000000cb11e38eb73dd5d612111f4461d953e90000000004800000a00000001000000085512ba758402a4c5f4504af6f407ba3180000003bf98f386b5341815358f54166f931802814a6154f86daf8140000009a3c5af0588baa420ed836dc0ac1d1f4d0fb4649"

$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $pass
$UserCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord

echo "Credentials received"  >> C:\Users\username\Desktop\ABC.txt

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

echo "Session"  >> C:\Users\username\Desktop\ABC.txt

Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber

echo "Session set up"  >> C:\Users\username\Desktop\ABC.txt

Remove-PSSession -Id $Session.Id
exit
```

When I run the same piece of code from powershell editor, it is getting executed correctly.
I am the expecting same behavior when it is scheduled from SQL Agent.

Comment: @Theo `echo` is NOT an alias for `Write-Host`, but `Write-Output`.  Your comment assertions are 100% wrong.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Ok, I have removed that comment. [Write-Output](https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle/issues/46#issuecomment-469449001) seems to be under discussion I believe.

Comment: @Theo In PowerShell **_Core_**? Sure.  But that's not what this question is about.

Answer (score 0):

As encryption is user specific we should create a proxy account at sql agent jobs for a user with whom password is encrypted. And then run the job with particular proxy. It works.

Encryption Technique used:

```
$password = read-host -prompt "Enter Password" 
write-host "$password is: " 
$secure = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -force -asPlainText 
$bytes = ConvertFrom-SecureString $secure 
#Encrypted Password
echo $bytes
```

Note:- enter code here Above mentioned technique is user and system specific. 
Please encrypt the password on the same machine from where you will be running the script in which you will be using the password.